# How to get from Reykjalið (Mývatn) to Askja without a car?

Tags: transportation, iceland

Any bus companies offer transport from Reykjalið (Mývatn) to Askja? Or maybe Hitchhiking?

Comment: It is worth noting that you are asking about travel to a point which is not part of the normal road network and is generally only accessible by specialized vehicles.

Answer (score 4):

The [Rough Guide Iceland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1409363813) (David Leffman, James Proctor) gives these details.

> **Tours from Reykjalið**
>
> If you don't want to take the following tours, you'll need to hire a car or bicycle from Hótel Reynihlíð or make use of the eight-kilometre-long Reykjalið-Grjótagjá-Hverfell Dimmuborgir hiking trail. The following excursions run in summer only; either contact operators direct or book through Mývatn's Visitor Centre.
>
> SBA **buses** (www.sba.is) runs return **day trips** from Akureyri round the lake and out to **Krafla** (9500kr), and an extended version out to **Dettifoss** in Jökulsárgljúfur National Park (10,500kr). It also operates three-day expeditions to ice caves and glacier traverses at **Kverkfjöll** and **Vatnajökull** (25,000kr; see Routes to Kverkfjöll).
>
> The track south from Mývatn to the Interior at **Askja** is covered by bus with Mývatn Tours (464 1920, www.askjatours.is; 14,000kr); this is a lengthy day-trip, though you can arrange in advance to stay at huts along the way and be collected another day. Mývatn Adventures (464 4164, www.myvatn.is; 28,000kr) does the same thing in super-jeeps, and also heads right down to the fringes of the Vatnajökull ice cap at **Lofthellier Ice Caves** (June-Sept daily; 7700kr), frozen lava caverns discovered in 1989 (35,000kr).
>
> For **scenic flights**, Mýflug Air (464 4400, www.myflug.is) out of Reykjalið can take you for a spin over Mývatn and Krafla, or out to Askja and Dettifoss, or out to Grimsey - trips last from twenty minutes to two hours and cost 10,000-39,500kr. Finally, you can arrange horseriding in the area through Hlið (464 4103).